# Returning Data Image = null using react-native

Tags: react-native

I creating image picker with react-native-image-crop-picker, all goes well... I got the data from the picker(path, mime, etc) but when I upload it into the server, the data keeps returning null

here's how I upload the image:

```
//this is my state
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      image: null,
      images: null
    ...
    };
  }
//this is my insert function
doTambah = async => {
    const {
      ...
      image,
    } = this.state;
    
    const req = {
      ...
      foto: image,
    };
    console.log(req);
    api
      .post('/tambah_produk', req)
      .then(res => {
        alert('data berhasil disimpan');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err);
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

//this is my picker function
pickSingle() {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      forceJpg: true,
      includeExif: true,
    })
      .then(image => {
        console.log('received image', image);
        this.setState({
          image: {
            uri: image.path,
            width: image.width,
            height: image.height,
            type: image.mime,
            size: image.size
          },
          images: null,
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        Alert.alert(e.message ? e.message : e);
      });
  }
//this is how I input image inside render
render() {
    ...
    const {
      ...
      image,
      images

    } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.formWrapper}>
          <View style={styles.formRow}>
            ...
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: hp('1%')}}>
            <Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}>Tambah Foto</Text>
            <ScrollView>
              {this.state.image ? this.renderAsset(this.state.image) : null}
              {this.state.images
                ? this.state.images.map(i => (
                    <View key={i.uri}>{this.renderAsset(i)}</View>
                  ))
                : null}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.pickSingle()}
            style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Upload Thumbnail</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.btnAddContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.btnAdd}
            onPress={() => this.doTambah()}>
            <Text style={styles.textBtnAdd}>Tambah Barang</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

when I try to log the image, the return data seems right

```
received image {"height": 1080, "mime": "image/jpeg", "modificationDate": "1628874621000", "path": "file:///data/user/0/com.gapoktanapps/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/IMG-20210813-WA0034.jpg", "size": 78463, "width": 1000}
```

but when I upload the image into server I keep getting error: data: null

[response error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekFBL.png)

why my data: null ? what's wrong ? and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use FormData to send post data:

```js
...
const data = new FormData();
data.append('foto', image);

api
   .post('/tambah_produk', data)
   .then(res => {
        alert('data berhasil disimpan');
   })
   .catch(err => {
      alert(err);
      console.log(err);
   });
...
```

EDIT:
After choose one image, set a name to `image`state:

```js
pickSingle() {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      forceJpg: true,
      includeExif: true,
    })
      .then(image => {
        console.log('received image', image);
        this.setState({
          image: {
            uri: image.path,
            width: image.width,
            height: image.height,
            type: image.mime,
            size: image.size,
            name: image.path.split('/').pop() // Add this property
          },
          images: null,
        });
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        Alert.alert(e.message ? e.message : e);
      });
  }
```

Comment: I've try using data.append, and nothing changed

Comment: I got difference log tho
{"_parts": [["kategori_id", 1], ["nama", ""], ["stok", 0], ["harga", 0], ["user_id", "2"], ["deskripsi", ""], ["android", true], ["foto", [Object]]]}

but still inside response "foto: null"

Comment: Try edited answer version. Use FormData with new name property

Comment: Yes, I use your answer and change my code, but still, the file is null... I tried to send image to database using this package

Comment: Maybe the error is in server. Post the server code

Comment: if (!$request->hasFile('foto')) {
                return $this->resp(null, Variable::FAILED, false, 406);
            } else {
                return $this->resp();
            }

this is how I check if my file is uploaded or not

Comment: ohh you've edited your answer, thank you, I'll try it soon